YouTube API 403 authenticatedUserAccountSuspended
I am getting the below error exception when trying to publish a video onto a YouTube channel.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError  The YouTube account of the authenticated user is suspended. In case the authenticated user is acting on behalf of another Google account, then this error refers to the latter. [403]  Errors [   Message[The YouTube account of the authenticated user is suspended. In case the authenticated user is acting on behalf of another Google account, then this error refers to the latter.] Location[ - ] Reason[authenticatedUserAccountSuspended] Domain[youtube.common]  ]
Is there a way to appeal to Google to look at the account?

Prehaps on Issue Tracker
